# Are there drivers for LG monitor 27MK400 for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I have a new LG monitor 27MK400 .are there drivers for this device for Ubuntu 18.04?I have a Dell Latitude laptop with Intel Sandybridge Mobile.(64 bit)

Comment: why would you need a diver when you connect a monitor to a laptop? That will be a connection over usb, dvi, hdmi... so what do you expect the driver to do?

Comment: I dont expect it to do anything.LG supplied a driver disc with drivers for windows and mac,no linux drivers.I solved the problem by returning the monitor to the retailer and buying one of a different brand that doesnt need drivers.It turned out the LG monitor didnt work on the same laptop with Windows 10.I put the linux HD back in and took it to the store and made sure the monitor I wanted worked.Lets hope this nonsense of needing drivers for a monitor isnt the wave of the future.